# xerces xinclude error

Tags: c++, xml, xerces, xinclude

I am using Apache Xerces 3.0.1 XInclude. I want to use the xinclude mechanism to include XML files. I have three XML files all in the same directory. test_a.xml xincludes test_b.xml which xincludes test_c.xml. When I just have test_a.xml xinclude test_b.xml, it works. However, when I have test_b.xml xinclude test_c.xml I get the following command line error:

C:\digital_receiver\test>XInclude.exe test_a.xml test_z.xml
Parse test_a.xml in progress ...
Fatal Error at file C:\digital_receiver\test/test_a.xml, line 3, char 34
Message: no scheme found in URI
finished.

test_a.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<test_a xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <xi:include href="test_b.xml"/>
</test_a>
```

test_b.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<test_b xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <ch>5</ch>
  <xi:include href="test_c.xml"/>
</test_b>
```

test_c:xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<test_c>
  <channel>1</channel>
</test_c>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your XML is OK, but I wouldn't claim to be the last word on this.

It's my *guess* that you're hitting a bug in Xerces' XInclude processing. I note that while this code is almost three years old, it apparently wasn't [released until Xerces 3.0](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/releases_archive.html#Release300), so it may be relatively untested. (And given the way that [base URIs of included documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#include_element) are handled in XInclude, the possibility of a bug here seems like it's greater than 0.)

As a workaround, I'd suggest doing what the error message suggests: add a scheme to the URIs for the included files. Unfortunately, for file URIs, that also means you need to use an absolute URI.

test_a.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<test_a xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <xi:include href="file://path/to/directory/test_b.xml"/>
</test_a>
```

test_b.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<test_b xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <ch>5</ch>
  <xi:include href="file://path/to/directory/test_c.xml"/>
</test_b>
```

UPDATE: There is indeed [a similar bug](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESC-1879) at apache.org. (I think it's describing the same issue, but the wording on the report makes it sound like even a **single** layer of inclusion would fail when using relative paths.)

Comment: Thanks Dan. I am able to get a single layer of inclusion to function properly. I guess I can wait until they fix the bug.